# Wamp2 and "The ordinal 942 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY.dll"

Tags: ssl, https, openssl, wamp

I want to learn to use SSL with Wamp, and I am using the article [Wamp2 HTTPS and SSL Setup Step-by-Step guide](http://www.wampserver.com/phorum/read.php?2,32986,page=1). When I type in the command `openssl genrsa -des3 -out server.key 1024` in the command line, it shows me an error ***`The ordinal 942 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY.dll.`***

How can I solve this problem ? Thank you!

Comment: Edit your system's PATH variable to exclude the location that contains the older openssl.exe or libeay.dll files. Otherwise, you might have an easier time using WampDeveloper and these instructions: http://new.devside.net/howto/create-ssl-certificates-for-apache

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Another application on your computer is using a different version of OpenSSL, and it has installed older library files. [Download OpenSSL](https://code.google.com/p/openssl-for-windows/downloads/detail?name=openssl-0.9.8k_WIN32.zip&can=2&q=), unzip it and run it from that directory.

Comment: Apache foundation provides [alternative binaries](http://www.apachelounge.com/download/win32/) with OpenSSL 1.0.1e. This worked for me.

Answer (score 17):

I have downloaded the latest openSSL and copied openssl.exe, libeay32.dll,ssleay32.dll to this location C:\wamp\bin\apache\Apache2.2.17\bin

It is working without errors. Thanks guys

Comment: I was also facing this problem and solved by doing as you told - thank you

Comment: Worked for me too, don't forget the previously (with error generated) certificate file if you are converting / creating certificate files (the one of size 0bytes...)