# Force user to install SSL certificate using php

Tags: php, ssl

Using this page: [Wamp2 and "The ordinal 942 could not be located in the dynamic link library LIBEAY.dll"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6178815/wamp2-https-and-ssl)
I was able to setup SSL on my wamp. It works nice, especially after I provide the server certificate (server.crt) to an user. If not, they will have an "certificate not trusted" error. It is possible to reject those who are not using SSL certificate?
Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the client displays a *"server certificate is not trusted"* message, that's because the server certificate you have installed is not signed by any authority the client knows about. Likely you're using a self-signed certificate. When you add this certificate to the trusted certificate store on your client, the client now trusts this certificate and does not display the warning anymore. It's not that "the client uses a certificate", it's that the client doesn't complain about the server's certificate.

You have no influence over this process at all. The server offers its certificate, and the client trusts it or doesn't. The server doesn't know this. If the client continues its conversation with the server, that pretty much implies that it trusts the offered certificate. Whether that is because the user approved it manually or because the client trusts the certificate otherwise, the server doesn't know.

There's also the concept of client certificates, in which a client identifies itself to the server using a certificate. This is badly supported in todays client software though and probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: I had no trouble using client SSL certs to access some services of a previous client of mine, they worked fine in all the browsers I was using (including Mobile Safari)

Comment: How did you install those client certificates on Mobile Safari?

Comment: @ - deceze. I installed certificates on IE, Chrome... and so on. And they work nice. I have a small number of users and they have concerns about the security of transmitted data. So, I want to MAKE them instal the certificate. :)

Comment: @deceze — I think I just made the client cert available on a secret, HTTPS, LAN URI and pointed the browser at it. Then followed the prompts. It was several years ago though.

Comment: I have a small organisation, I issue my own certificates and I can verify them, but I want them installed.

Comment: From what you're describing you're not installing client certificates, you are just adding an untrusted *server* certificate to the client's trusted certificate store. Again: you have a self-signed certificate not signed by anyone (right?!), so the browser complains about a lack of trust in the certificate, so you tell the browser it can trust the certificate by installing it locally, so the browser doesn't complain anymore. That's not a client certificate and it cannot be detected by the server.

Comment: If you don't want to spend money on actual signed certificates (which is perfectly okay) but make the process of managing certificates easier, you can create your own *signing authority certificate* and install *that* on all your clients once. You can then use this signing authority certificate to sign any number of other certificates, which all clients will implicitly trust without complaint.

Comment: OK.... I created my own signing authority certificate. I can see if my clients installed the certificate? Can I block those who prefer just to "trust"? Or am I wrong?

Comment: Again: no. The server doesn't know *why* the client trusts its certificate.

Comment: *"Hey, server! I don't trust you, but I'm still talking to ya!"* - uhm... ;-P

Comment: or "Hey, server! I trust you and I have installed the certificate you issued!" - this is basically my question! :))